# How to import data from another file in javascript/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
export default () => {
    return [
        {
            text: 'Full-time',
            value: 'fulltime',
            key: 'fulltime'
        },
        {
            text: 'Part-time',
            value: 'parttime',
            key: 'parttime',
        },
        {
            text: 'Freelance',
            value: 'freelance',
            key: 'freelance',
        },
    ]
};
```

And then in my component I could get that data to use in a dropdown like this:

```
import { positionTypeOptions } from '../components/data/PositionTypes';

<Form.Select label="&nbsp;" placeholder="Type" options={positionTypeOptions} width={3} />
```

However the data does not seem to be exported. The data in undefined. Any ideas how this could be done? I would like to return an array to be used in another component.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not seem to be exported? Do you have any error? What does positionTypeOptions evaluate?

Comment: sorry updated the question with positionTypeOptions  in {}, which returns undefined. When I do it without {} it returns a function and i want an array

Answer (score 5):

You are exporting an anonymous function as default. Try this:

```
export const positionTypeOptions = [
    {
        text: 'Full-time',
        value: 'fulltime',
        key: 'fulltime'
    },
    {
        text: 'Part-time',
        value: 'parttime',
        key: 'parttime',
    },
    {
        text: 'Freelance',
        value: 'freelance',
        key: 'freelance',
    },
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to return a function from the export. Just return an `object`, like this:

```
export default {
    [
        {
            text: 'Full-time',
            value: 'fulltime',
            key: 'fulltime'
        },
        {
            text: 'Part-time',
            value: 'parttime',
            key: 'parttime',
        },
        {
            text: 'Freelance',
            value: 'freelance',
            key: 'freelance',
        },
    ]
};
```

*For the import,* **remove the curly brackets since you have a default export**:

```
import positionTypeOptions from '../components/data/PositionTypes';
```